# Google maps api: get municipality of a point

Tags: google-maps-api

Is it possible to get the municipality at a given coordinate in Google maps api? I know there are maps with the municipal information, but how to get the municipal of a given point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get information about administrative districts. You want the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start). The process you are suggesting is generally called 'reverse geocoding'. i.e. going from lat,long to place name.

Information about the response you get, including administrative area types, is available [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#reverse-response). Scroll down to `Address Types and Address Component Types`.

Exactly how your local 'municipality' will line up with google's schema may take some trial and error.

Comment: Thanks!! This is what I was looking for. I guess it should be 'administrative_area_level_2'. Still: should I need to be online to use these, or a database can be downloaded (say, by country)?